# ios: disable alert notification when app in focus (OneSignal)

Tags: ios, push-notification, react-native, onesignal

I use OneSignal sdk for react native. I try disable the internal alarm when the app in focus. Do you have an idea how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
OneSignal.configure({
onIdsAvailable: function (device) {
  console.log('UserId = ', device.userId);
 console.log('PushToken = ', device.pushToken);
 getUserId(device.userId);
 },
 onNotificationReceived: function (notification) {
OneSignal.checkPermissions((permissions) => {
  console.log(permissions);
 });
OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);
},
onNotificationOpened: function(message, data, isActive) {
 console.log("MS TYPE", message);
 switch(message.notification.payload.additionalData.type) {
 case '1':
       Actions.messenger({id:     message.notification.payload.additionalData.userID});
    break;
case '2':
      Actions.overview();
    break;
  }
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is where you place `OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);`

You need to put it on `componentWillMount` like

```
  componentWillMount () {
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived.bind(this))
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened)
    OneSignal.addEventListener('registered', this.onRegistered)
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds.bind(this))

    // Set inFocusDisplaying to prevent the default push notification alert when the is in focus
    // Android ONLY
    OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0)
  }
```

Comment: this has changed since version 4.0. One should call `OneSignal.disablePush(boolean)` now as `inFocusDisplaying` is removed from new api

Comment: Ok @pavle Could you please update the answer as I have switched to Flutter since years now :D